# Stopping Neotree from constantly switching to the open file's directory?

Tags: projectile, neotree

I have the problem that, even when I'm in a projectile project, NeoTree always switches to the directory of the currently open file in the active buffer. Which is annoying to say the least.

It used to behave the right way, but (probably with a recent update?) that changed. How can I get the correct behaviour back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people googling that, if you don't have the "use-package" package, you can also simply put that in your .emacs:

```
(setq neo-autorefresh nil)
(require 'neotree)
```

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here. I could solve it disabling `neo-autorefresh` variable.

My configuration with `use-package`:

```
(use-package neotree
  :ensure t
  :bind (([f8] . neotree-toggle))
  :config (setq neo-autorefresh nil))
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why that's not on their docs - https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NeoTree

Answer (score 0):

You describe the behavior of neotree with the `neo-smart-open` variable set. Make sure this is set to `nil` in your `~.emacs`, or simply remove this config, as the default value for this is `nil`.